# How many $10$-letter sequences can be made from five different vowels and five different consonants?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ten letter sequences can be made from five different vowels and five different consonants (selected from the twenty-one possible consonants)?

Comment: Kindly include your thoughts and attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  how many ways to choose which consonants you use?  Once you have them, how many ways to order the letters?

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom55$ ways to choose the vowels and $\binom{22}5$ ways to choose the consonants.

Each of these ten-letter combinations can be arranged in ${}_{10}P_{10}$ sequences.

Thus the total number of ways equals

$$\binom{5}{5}\binom{22}{5}\left({}_{10}P_{10}\right) = (1)(26\,334)(3\,628\,800) = 95\,560\,819\,200$$